# Suppose $f(0),f(1),...,f(10)$ are in a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac{1}5$. In which interval does $\int_0^{10} f(x)dx$ lie?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

> Let $f : R \to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous decreasing function. Suppose $f(0),f(1),...,f(10)$ are in a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac{1}5$.In which of the following intervals does the value of $\int_0^{10}f(x)dx$ lie?

> ${(a)(0, 2f(0))\\
>  (b)(4f(0),6f(0))\\
>  (c)(8f(0),10f(0))\\
>  (d)(12f(0),14f(0)}$

From the question,$$f(n)=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^nf(0)$$

Clearly, $$\sum_{n=1}^{9}f(n)\le\int_0^{10}f(x)dx\le\sum_{n=0}^{9}f(n)$$

Now, $$\sum_{n=1}^{9}f(n)=f(0)\left[\frac{1}5+\frac{1}{5^2} +\frac{1}{5^3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{5^{9}}\right]\approx0.25f(0)$$

And,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{9}f(n)=f(0)\left[1+\frac{1}5+\frac{1}{5^2} +\frac{1}{5^3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{5^{9}}\right]\approx1.25f (0)$$

$$\therefore \frac{1}{4}f(0)\le\int_0^{10}f(x)dx\le\frac{5}{4}f(0)$$

Is it correct? Any suggestion or alternative method is highly solicited.

Comment: Then $0<0.25f(0)$ and $1.25f(0)<2f(0)$, assuming your previous steps are correct.

Comment: As @peterwhy commented, if your evaluation is correct, the interval in the first option covers the range you found...

Comment: @peterwhy edited.  Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think now your progress is enough to pick one of the multiple choices.

Comment: To nitpick, as both $\sum_{n=1}^9 \frac1{5^n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac1{5^n}$ are strictly less than $\frac14$, it's still possible that $\frac14 f(0) > \int_0^{10}f(x)\ dx$: $$\exists f: f(0) \sum_{n=1}^9 \frac1{5^n} < f(0) \sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac1{5^n} \le \int_0^{10}f(x)\ dx < \frac14f(0)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nitpick your attempt, as both $\sum_{n=1}^9 \frac1{5^n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac1{5^n}$ are strictly less than $\frac14$, it's still possible that $\frac14 f(0) > \int_0^{10}f(x)\ dx$:

$$\exists f: f(0) \sum_{n=1}^9 \frac1{5^n} < f(0) \sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac1{5^n} \le \int_0^{10}f(x)\ dx < \frac14f(0)$$

---

For a looser bound of the integral that's sufficient to pick one of the multiple choices:

For $n = 0,1,\ldots, 9$, since $f$ is decreasing and always positive,

$$0 < \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\ dx \le f(n)$$

Summing from $n=0$ to $9$,

$$\begin{align*}
0 < \sum_{n=0}^9 \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\ dx &\le \sum_{n=0}^9 f(x)\\
\int_0^{10} f(x)\ dx &\le f(0) \sum_{n=0}^9 \frac1{5^n}\\
&< f(0) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{5^n}\\
&= f(0)\cdot \frac{1}{1-1/5}\\
&= \frac54 f(0)\\
&< 2f(0)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. To be more rigorous, you could just say that $$af(0)\le\int_0^{10}f(n)dn\le5af(0)$$Where $a=\frac15\frac{1-\frac1{5^{10}}}{1-\frac15}$. Your approximations are sufficient for intuition though. Also, $5a<1.25$ and $a>0$, so the answer is a).